# “Jumping” among several interpolation techniques?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spatial, boosting, interpolation, kriging

I am comparing several interpolation methods using monthly climatic data, through RMSE and a 10-fold cross-validation scheme. 
What I'm observing is that the performances vary from one month to another, and a given method is better than the others in a given month, while it's outperformed by another in the next one. Kinda TPS performs better in JAN, JUL, JUN, RF in FEB, MAR, APR, and so on. 
Given that, I'm wondering if it is correct to mix these results by picking the best monthly interpolations independently of the method that created it. That is, TPS for JAN, RF for FEB, and so on. Thanx!

Comment: It is unclear what the validation method used. Be very careful about how we estimate out-of-performance.

Comment: Sorry, but 10-fold cross-validation is a standard and widely known validation procedure and, hence, I think it isn't necessary to explain it here, and is independent on the main focus of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. If indeed "standard" 10-fold CV was used that is would be misleading because we would have data leakage. When we are analysing time-series data we need to ensure that we do not have information from "the future" leaking into our training set. i.e. when training the RF on predicting April, all the data from May onwards should also be excluded. We need to consider what is described a [time-series crossvalidation](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data was used with each month being analyzed independently: the data from January for January, etc.